# How do I display visitor fullname on my facebook fan page welcome tab?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api

I have created my fan page using `Page Tab`.

Now I want to display visitor Full Name on that page.

Example : Hello `Fullname`

It's possible without authentication?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Name/UID on page tab without authentication?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7602320/name-uid-on-page-tab-without-authentication)

Comment: not possible anymore without authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the Javascript SDK to achieve this, [here's the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

... and in answer to your second question, you'll need to get authorisation of use user for your app to make any Graph API request.

You'll need to get the user's name by doing an API request to `/me?fields=name` get the username.

Comment: This requires authentication first.

Comment: Sorry you're right, you need the authorisation code for any request to the Graph API.  I've corrected my answer, please +1 :)